# Can't create valid sitemap.xml file for Google

Tags: sitemap, hugo, xml-sitemap, sitemap.xml

I am using Hugo to generate my site and am manually adding a sitemap.xml file by placing it in
layouts/sitemap.xml.

No matter what sitemap.xml file I try I get this message when I point my browser to the sitemap URL, `https://www.example.ca/sitemap.xml`. The page is empty.
[image]

sitemap.xml generated from: https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->


<url>
  <loc>https://www.example.ca/</loc>
  <lastmod>2021-03-25T13:24:33+00:00</lastmod>
</url>


</urlset>
```

Comment: Using a crawler (like xml-sitemaps.com) is pointless.   If the crawler can generate your sitemap, search engine bots can crawl your site without it.   XML sitemaps should always be generated by querying your database and never generated with a crawler.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: ixodid your question isn't worded in a way that can be answered.
1. Where did you put the sitemap.xml file? 2. What is the content of sitemap.xml? 3. What is hugo server generating if anything? How are you building the site... etc. etc. etc. Supply those and then this is an easy fix.

Comment: Why are you putting the `sitemap.xml` in the `layouts` folder, rather than the root folder?